# "_ was unexpected at this time" error

Tags: batch-file

I made a batch file, and i put in this code:

```
if %VAR% == _,_,_ set VAR=%S1le1%,_,_
```

When i tried the batch file, it just said "_ was unexpected at this time"

```
%VAR% = _,_,_
%S1le1% = b
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the current value of `%var%` and `%S1le1%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with :

```
if "%VAR%" == "_,_,_" set "VAR=%S1le1%,_,_"
```

`,` is a standard delimiter and when its found by `IF` after the comparison expression  is taken as the end of the IF. With quotes it should compare the whole strings.